# Replacing light fixture, current box has too many wires for new fixture

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I've been working on setting up a new light fixture for a few hours now and ran into a bit of a problem.  This fixture was replaced about 6 years ago with the current one, so it's not too old, but it's old enough for me to be confused about what to do when replacing it.

[image: With new light fixture]

Here's our new fixture setup with bracket in place and the fixture's ground wire attached to the ground screw and house ground wire.  We see 3 white wires, a ground wire, and a black wire coming from the outlet.  The black and single white wires are both hot and the two white wires are both neutral, and were already tied together when we replaced the fixture.  So far that's about all we've done, since we're not sure where to put the new wires.  The clear tubes are both from the new fixture, one having text on it and another being completely clear.  The guide says to attach the clearest wire to the neutral white wire and attach the clear wire with text to the hot black wire.  But doing that leaves us with a hot white wire by itself, so that's where we're stuck.  Mainly wondering where we should go from here?  The fixture model is a Hampton Bay 3 light chandelier if that helps.

Comment: How was the original fixture wired? Have you tried wiring the new one the same way?

Comment: Why  do the two wires have blue tape on them?